# How to trigger validation on an FormArray?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-forms, formarray

I have a form which contains an object. In this object I have two 'normal' attributes and one form array. In my case I need to check if a object a field of an object in the form array is a port or a portrange. For that I have a regex. But in my case the validation is never shown (no red input-field or mat-error).

Typescript

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9._-\\s]*$')]],
      description: ['', Validators.maxLength(255)],
      elements: new FormArray([this.createElement()])
    });
...
createElement(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      'portRanges': ['', [Validators.required]],
      'protocol': ['',[Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^\d+$|^\d+-\d+$')]]
    });
}
```

```
<div formArrayName="elements" *ngFor="let e of elements.controls; let i = index;">
  <div [formGroupName]="i">
    <mat-form-field class="field">
      <input tabindex="3" matInput placeholder="Port or range *" formControlName="portRanges"/>
      <mat-error>Between 0 and 65535, or a range of two such numbers separated by a dash ( - )</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select a protocol" [ngStyle]="getStyle(e)" formControlName="protocol">
      <mat-radio-button value="TCP" tabindex="4">TCP</mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button value="UDP" tabindex="5">UDP</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>

    <div style="display: flex">
      <div>
        <div *ngIf="i === elements.controls.length - 1" style="margin-right: 5px;" class="action-btn" tabindex="6" (click)="addBlankElement()">
          <i class="material-icons">add_circle</i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="elements.length > 1" class="action-btn remove-btn" tabindex="7" (click)="removeElement(i)">
        <i class="material-icons">remove_circle</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Solved by checking all elements after value changes:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.createForm();
  this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
    this.validate(this.myForm);
  })
}

validate(group: FormGroup = this.myForm){
  this.elements.controls.forEach((data) => {
    data.updateValueAndValidity();
  })
}
```

Comment: Can I see your .html too?

Comment: I have added the HTML part for you

Comment: I must supouse you has a getter `get element(){return myForm.get('elements') as FormArray}`. Really I don't understand your validator RegExprex over "protocol". You has a radio button, it's not possible options else the values of radio buttons or null

Comment: You are completely right. This was one error. I also had to update the validity of each element in the form array after valueChanges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you have to use `updateValueAndValidity` to update the validation -

```
this.myForm.get('name').updateValueAndValidity();
this.myForm.get('description').updateValueAndValidity();
```

and then

```
this.myForm.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: where should I add this? after adding a new element?

Comment: call this on `ngOnInit()` after the declaration.

Comment: ngOnInit(){
  this.createForm();
  this.myForm.get('name').updateValueAndValidity();
  this.myForm.get('description').updateValueAndValidity();
  this.myForm.updateValueAndValidity();
}

Comment: you were right. I had to upate all elements validity after valueChanges.(see edit)